# Inline if else?

Tags: javascript, python, if-statement

Here is part of code. I need to understand what this code do :

```py
if instruction == "JOINT" or instruction == "ROOT":
    parent = joint_stack[-1] if instruction == "JOINT" else None
    joint = BvhJoint(words[1], parent)
    self.joints[joint.name] = joint
```

How to understand this line special ->

```
    parent = joint_stack[-1] if instruction == "JOINT" else None
```

Is this code equal with JS code:

```js
if (instruction == "JOINT") {
    parent = joint_stack[-1];
} else {

}
```

?

Comment: Why 7 questions about similar theme was automatic flages i negative voited. Looks like a anathema. I finnaly got my script : If someone looks for bvh js loader _ https://codepen.io/zlatnaspirala/pen/mdXzeKR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent JS code would be:

```
   if (instruction == "JOINT") { 
        parent = joint_stack[-1];
    } else {
        parent = null;
    }
```

or more idiomatically:

```
    parent = instruction == "JOINT" ? joint_stack[-1] : null;
```

This ternary expression in Python:

```
joint_stack[-1] if instruction == "JOINT" else None
```

is the same as the JS ternary expression:

```
instruction == "JOINT" ? joint_stack[-1] : null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 parent = joint_stack[-1] if instruction == "JOINT" else None
```

This will check the “instruction” is equal to “JOINT” if yes, last value of joint_stack array will be assigned to the parent, otherwise `None`

Comment: The condition it's checking is `instruction == "JOINT"`, not `joint_stack[-1] == "JOINT"`.

Answer (score 1):

The JS equivalent would be

```
const parent = (instruction === "JOINT")?joint_stack[-1]:null;
```

The [shortcut to conditional
expression was added to Python 2.5.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html) See [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)